# I have two tables and I want to merge them using R based on the SampleID

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Table 1:

| SampleID | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S101 | 1 | 23 | 24 |
| S102 | 1 | 26 | 28 |
| S103 | 2 | 22 | 40 |

Table 2:

| SampleID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S101 | 1 | 23 | 24 | 99 |
| S102 | 1 | 26 | 28 | 56 |
| S103 | 2 | 22 | 40 | 78 |
| S104 | 3 | 45 | 46 | 23 |

When I use merge for this based on SampleID this is what I am getting:

| SampleID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S101 | 1 | 23 | 24 | NA |
| S101 | NA | NA | NA | 99 |
| S102 | 1 | 26 | 28 | NA |
| S102 | NA | NA | NA | 56 |
| S103 | 2 | 22 | 40 | NA |
| S103 | NA | NA | NA | 78 |
| S104 | 3 | 45 | 46 | 23 |
| S104 | NA | NA | NA | 23 |

what I am expecting is:

| SampleID | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S101 | 1 | 23 | 24 | 99 |
| S102 | 1 | 26 | 28 | 56 |
| S103 | 2 | 22 | 40 | 78 |
| S104 | 3 | 45 | 46 | 23 |

Comment: Could you share the code you used also?

Comment: covariates_merge <- merge(x = hormonal, y = poa, by = "SampleID", all = TRUE)
View(covariates_merge)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: BTW your Table 2 and the expected output seems to be identical

Comment: I am sorry about that, imagine we have more column in table two that needs to be added

Comment: in base R just do `merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Using a `merge()` like this would get you the two tables merged as you want

```
merge(Table1,Table2,all=TRUE)



Output:

  sampleID a  b  c  d
1     S101 1 23 24 99
2     S102 1 26 28 56
3     S103 2 22 40 78
4     S104 3 45 46 23
```

Comment: When I use leftjoin() it is removing the duplicates but it is ging NA's for all the first table data